# Разбиение на части символов %s при методе join

Tags: python, pymysql

```
def insert_mysql(table: str, column_values: dict):
    columns = ', '.join(column_values.keys())
    values = tuple(column_values.values())
    placeholders = ", ".join("%s" * len(column_values.keys()))
    sql = (f"INSERT INTO {table} ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders})")
        
    return (sql, values)
```

Получаю на выходе:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (name, age) VALUES (%, s, %, s)
```

А должен:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (name, age) VALUES (%s, %s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> placeholders = ", ".join("%s" * len(column_values.keys()))
> ```

```
placeholders = ", ".join(["%s"] * len(column_values.keys()))
```

https://ideone.com/LTrYjt

```
print(", ".join("%s" * 2))
print(", ".join(["%s"] * 2))
```

```
%, s, %, s
%s, %s
```

Comment: То есть умножаем список и потом соединяем его элементы. Понятно, спасибо!